# Have Mountain Lion remember different monitor (not window) arrangement

Tags: macos, display

I'm using 10.8 on a new retina MacBook.

At home, my external monitor (an HP) is located to the **left** of the laptop stand. So I want it my display arrangement to be [HP] [MacBook].

At work, my external monitor (a Viewsonic) is located to **right** of the laptop stand. So I want the layout there to be [Macbook] [Viewsonic].

Under 10.6 it used to remember the layout as part of the monitor profile. Now, that no longer seems to be the case.

Does anyone know whether this is the new normal behavior, or how to fix it?

Comment: Along the same lines, if you've got two external monitors (chained Thunderbolts, in my case) and you disconnect and reconnect a Macbook to the same monitors, it will randomly assign the display arrangement every time. This is with the latest Mavericks. Seems to still be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting up your screens with [SwitchResX](http://www.madrau.com/srx_howtouseit/srx_howtouseit/srx_display_sets.html)?
It has settings for each unique display connected to your computer. The app cost a couple of dollars, but theres a 30day demo to try if it helps you.